# How would amphibious cone-aliens have 150 feet of tongue?

Tags: xenobiology

The Esuriensi are slick-skinned amphibious cone creatures. They hatch in water and drift on currents for a few days, then hit rock. Once they hit a rock, they anchor to it and live the rest of their lives (around 30-45 years) completely sessile. How do they live so long if they’re just cones stuck to the side of tide pools, you might ask? A 150-foot tongue. Only one problem: I don’t know how to make this work with biology. How would these creatures be structured to have such a long tongue?

Comment: You probably want a hydra, they have a set of tentacles that spread around and filter stuff, if anything found they contract and bring whatever they get into their mouth. So for a 150-foot tongue you need it to start at the deepest point of your aliens and be able to stick to prey and contract to bring it to whatever digestive device they have. Yet there's a limit on contraction factor, I doubt it'll be bigger than 10, thus your aliens have to have 15 feet of length to have that long tongue.

Comment: However, consider its tensile strength and whether it'll sway under currents when expanded, and whether a loss of tongue would lead to your alien's death of hunger. Hydrae have several tentacles for this very reason. Also what about mating and reproduction? Hydrae can travel and are able to replicate by spawning a new one out of its body, with your aliens be locked in place it'll look like the only way to reproduce for them.

Comment: The [tube-lipped nectar bat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube-lipped_nectar_bat) stores its tongue in its rib cage. However, more to the point, must the Esuriensi draw the tongue back inside the body at any time? Certainly it's not 150 feet at birth, so the tongue grows as the body does. Is there a limit to the size of the body? What happens when 150 foot tongues become tangled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Aggregate Organism**

[image]

The *tongue* is a chain of small creatures attached end-to-end. Like a [colony of salps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salp). Each blastozooid has a filter but they also share nutrients with each other, and pass the nutrients down the chain to the creature's body.

Wait -- just one massive tongue? What a silly idea, to put all your eggs in the one basket. If that tongue breaks you are stuffed! This is why squid and jellyfish have many small tentacles and not one long tentacle.

Fortunately this creature wants the tongue to break. Because when it does, the severed end of the tongue becomes free swimming and enters the second stage of its life cycle. Like [the mighty salp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salp), the creature has two distinct life stages and two forms of reproduction.

While attached to the rock, the blastozooids reproduce asexually and make the tongue longer. While freeswimming, the severed tongues mate with other tongues. They lay tiny eggs that drift about, attach to a rock, and it starts all over again.

Comment: liked the "emergence" topic here, where once the organisms aggregated into a tongue to taste something, they could aggregate into a digestive tube or any other organ they need at the moment.

Comment: @qqjkztd If they are anything like salps then they are attached to each other. So they cannot change shape at the moment.

Comment: in the sense thousands of ants can "morph into a bridge" for other individual ants to cross a gap that is otherwise individually not crossable.